# Basic JavaScript OOP model object

Tags: javascript, object-oriented

I'm relatively new to JavaScript OOP and would like to know the best practice when doing a simple object such as a Model.

Here's a piece of code representing class named `Child`:

What I'm asking for is:

1. The usage of this (and the weak reference I'm doing which I name self)
2. The global shape of the code (methods in prototype etc)
3. Declaring a class as a function, or with JSON semantics

```
var Child = function( json ) {
    var self = this;
    // Properties
    this.id = 0;
    this.firstname = "";
    this.moneyCurrent = 0;
    this.moneyDue = 0;
    this.missionsPlay = 0;
    this.missionsWait = 0;
    this.missionsStop = 0;

    this.missions = [];

    this.initialize( json );
}

Child.prototype = {
    initialize: function( json ) {
        var self = this;
        self.id = json.id_child;
        self.firstname = json.firstname;
        self.moneyCurrent = parseFloat(json.already_paid) + parseFloat(json.to_pay) - parseFloat(json.spent_money);
        self.moneyDue = parseFloat(json.to_pay);
        self.missionsPlay = json.nb_missions.in_progress;
        self.missionsWait = json.nb_missions.waiting;
        self.missionsStop = json.nb_missions.completed;
    },

    getMissions: function( type, callback ) {
        var self = this;
        session.requestServer( "parent_getChildMissionList", {
            sid: session.sid,
            id_child: self.id,
            status: type ? type : "",
            strict_status: false,
            page: 0
        }, function( data ){
            var missions = [];
            $(data.missionList).each(function(){
                self.missions.push(new Mission(this));
                missions.push(self.missions[self.missions.length-1]);
            });
            callback( missions );
        });
    },
};
```

Classic way to declare a class:

```
var obj = function() { 
    var attribut = "foo";
    this.metho = function(parameter1, parametre2) { 
        alert("parameters: " + parameter1 + ", " + parameter2); 
    } 
}
```

JSON way to declare a class:

```
var obj = { 
    attribut: "foo", 
    method: function(parameter1, parameter2) { 
        alert("parameters: " + parameter1 + ", " + parameter2); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your questions:

- The usage of `this` : In my mind, unless you are using closures, do not use `self = this`, so only keep it in `getMissions`
- Functions in `prototype` <- Good stuff
- Function <> JSON, is an odd question. You want to use constructors, and those are functions.

Other than that,

- You are using lowerCamelCase, that is good. Though `firstname` -> `firstName`
- `initialize: function( json )` does not really get a JSON string, instead it gets an object, so I would not name that parameter `json`
- The function to deal with returned missions seems a bit clumsy, I would either assign each new mission to a variable and push it to both arrays:

  ```
  function( data ){
      var missions = [], mission;
      $(data.missionList).each(function(){
          mission = new Mission(this)
          self.missions.push( mission );
          missions.push( mission );
      });
      callback( missions );
  }
  ```

  or, I would only `push` to `missions` and then concatenate `missions` into `self.missions`

  ```
  function( data ){
      var missions = [];
      $(data.missionList).each(function(){
          missions.push(new Mission(this));
      });
      self.missions = self.missions.concat( missions );
      callback( missions );
  }
  ```

All in all, nice code, very maintainable and self explanatory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's wath I searched as an answer, especially the "Other than that" really usefull :)
I edited my question to try to be clearer on my 3th question (sometime I lack to express myself). I read it  in a course but they don't say which one could be better and why. I wonder about it.

Comment: Singletons -> 'JSON Way', if you are going to have many objects of the same type -> constructor functions

Comment: In which way JSON Way is less good for reusable class than *constructor functions* ?

Comment: I would use map instead of each in those last 2 examples

Comment: +1 for `self = this` seeing that convention used improperly bothers me way more than it should.

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually need the `self` variable in most of your code (the constructor doesn't use it at all). You can just use `this` directly in most cases.

The only exception is in the `session.requestServer` callback, where you do need a way to reference the object context - and there it's perfectly fine to use `self`. Alternatively, you can use [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to derive a function that's bound to the right context (but if you're targeting browsers know that [support for `bind` is spotty](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Function.prototype.bind)).

More generally, I'd skip the `initialize` method. It depends on what you intend of course, but having the `initialize` function there means that you can re-initialize a `Child` instance whenever you want, because it'll have a publicly accessible `initialize` function that anyone can call. But initializing an instance should be the responsibility of the constructor function, unless there's some good reason to do otherwise. In this case, however, I don't think there is.

In other words, simply put everything in the constructor function, and remove the `initialize` function.

I end up with this; the "classic" way to define a class (i.e. construtor+prototype) in javascript.

```
function Child(json) { // equivalent to `var Child = function ...`; just for illustration
  // properties - with defaults
  this.id = json.id_child || 0; // null might be a better default for the ID
  this.firstname = json.firstname || "";
  this.moneyDue = parseFloat(json.to_pay) || 0;
  this.moneyCurrent = parseFloat(json.already_paid) + this.moneyDue - parseFloat(json.spent_money) || 0;
  this.missionsPlay = json.nb_missions.in_progress || 0;
  this.missionsWait = json.nb_missions.waiting || 0;
  this.missionsStop = json.nb_missions.completed || 0;

  this.missions = [];
}

Child.prototype = {
  getMissions: function (type, callback) {
    var self = this;

    // I assume `session` is a global or closed-over variable?
    session.requestServer( "parent_getChildMissionList", {
      sid:      session.sid,
      id_child: this.id,     // we can still use `this` here
      status:   type || "",
      strict_status: false,
      page: 0
    }, function (data) {
      var missions = [],
      mission;
      $(data.missionList).each(function () {
        mission = new Mission(this); // easier than having to go through missions[missions.length-1]
        self.missions.push(mission); // This is where we need to use the `self` var
        missions.push(mission);
      });
      callback(missions);
    });
  } // removed a stray comma on this line - some JS interpreters choke on them, some don't
};
```

Now, you could conceivably just use the JSON more directly. Perhaps have a factory-like method that takes in the "raw" JSON, and add a few things or builds a new object literal from it. That'd look something like:

```
function buildChild(json) { // note lowercase naming; this isn't a constructor
  var child = {
    id: json.id_child || 0,
    firstname: json.firstname || "",
    moneyDue: parseFloat(json.to_pay) || 0,
    moneyCurrent: parseFloat(json.already_paid) + this.moneyDue - parseFloat(json.spent_money) || 0,
    missionsPlay: json.nb_missions.in_progress || 0,
    missionsWait: json.nb_missions.waiting || 0,
    missionsStop: json.nb_missions.completed || 0,
    missions: [],
  };

  child.getMissions = function (type, callback) {
    session.requestServer( "parent_getChildMissionList", {
      sid:      session.sid,
      id_child: child.id,     // now we use `child` instead of this
      status:   type || "",
      strict_status: false,
      page: 0
    }, function (data) {
      var missions = [],
      mission;
      $(data.missionList).each(function () {
        mission = new Mission(this);
        child.missions.push(mission); // same here
        missions.push(mission);
      });
      callback(missions);
    });
  };

  return child;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want to avoid classical style but still use prototypes for performance or manageability...

```
var Child = {
  // defaults values for inherited properties
  id: 0,
  firstname = "",
  moneyCurrent = 0,
  moneyDue = 0,
  missionsPlay = 0,
  missionsWait = 0,
  missionsStop = 0,
  missions = [],

  // factory method which creates new instances and prototype factories
  create: function(options) {
    var obj = Object.create(this),
        proto = obj,
        inits = [];

    // fetch all defined init methods in the prototype chain
    while (proto && proto !== Object.prototype) {
      if (proto.hasOwnProperty("init")) inits.push(proto.init);
      proto = proto.getPrototypeOf();
    }

    // execute inits
    inits.reverse.forEach(function(init) {init.call(this, options);});
  },

  // constructor for your "class"
  init: function(options) {
    // validate input
    var money = parseFloat(options.already_paid) + parseFloat(options.to_pay)
            - parseFloat(options.spent_money),
        due = parseFloat(options.to_pay),
        play = parseInt(options.nb_missions.in_progress),
        wait = parseInt(options.nb_missions.waiting),
        stop = parseInt(options.nb_missions.completed);

    // use validated input or fallback to inherited values
    this.id = options.id_child || this.id;
    this.firstname = options.firstname || this.firstname;
    this.moneyCurrent = isNaN(money) ? this.moneyCurrent : money;
    this.moneyDue = isNaN(due) ? this.moneyDue : due;
    this.missionsPlay = isNaN(play) ? this.missionsPlay : play;
    this.missionsWait = isNaN(wait) ? this.missionsWait : wait;
    this.missionsStop = isNaN(stop) ? this.missionsStop : stop;

    // ensure we have our own copy of the missions array
    this.missions = this.missions.slice(0);
  },

  getMissions: function(type, callback) {
    // ...
  }      
};
```

So now creating a new child with Child.create will setup the appropriate
prototype chain.  You could then create a manageable inheritance hierarchy.

```
var c, FooChild = Child.create();

c = FooChild.create();
FooChild.foo = "FOO!";
assert(c.foo == "FOO!");
```

Comment: Really interesting